# python3.5.4 no inicia con pythonw, pero si se ejecuta con el IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5.4
## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#from tkinter import *                  # Gestor grafico tkinter
import sqlite3                          # Motor de Base de datos

clv_bd = sqlite3.connect('cddpbd.db')   # Abrir Base de Datos SQLite3
cur_bd = clv_bd.cursor()

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import time

canvas = canvas.Canvas("D:\Proyectos\ComunaDDP\ImpresionPdf\Ejemplo-Reportlab-canvas.pdf", pagesize=letter) # Tamaño de la pagina
canvas.setLineWidth(.1)

def encabezado(pag):
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 10)                                                                         # Tipo de letra
#   canvas.drawImage("ag00130.gif", 0, letter[1]/2, width=400, height=400)                                  # Insertar imagen
    canvas.drawString(210,760,'Republica Bolivariana de Venezuela')
    date = (time.strftime('Fecha: '+"%d/%m/%Y"))
    canvas.drawString(500,760,date)

    canvas.drawString(220,748,'Pavia, Barquisimeto, Estado Lara')
    canvas.drawString(500,748,'Pagina: '+str(pag))

    reporte='Reporte de Habitantes por Comuna'
    canvas.drawString(217,736,reporte)

    canvas.drawString(30,710,"Apellido              Nombre            C. Identidad    Nro. Telefono    Sector                           Consejo Comunal")
    canvas.line(30,705,580,705)

pag=1
encabezado(pag)

lpp=0
x=0
y=705
cur_bd.execute("SELECT * FROM habitantes ORDER BY apellido ASC")

for i in cur_bd:
    ced_HAB=(i[0])
    voe_HAB=(i[1])
    nom_HAB=(i[2])
    ape_HAB=(i[3])
    dir_SEC=(i[10])
    tel_MOV=(i[12])
    con_COM=(i[15])

    x=30
    y=y-10
    canvas.drawString(x,y,ape_HAB)
    canvas.drawString(x+75,y,nom_HAB)
    v=len(ced_HAB)
    if v==7:
        canvas.drawString(x+156,y,ced_HAB)
    else:
        canvas.drawString(x+150,y,ced_HAB)
    canvas.drawString(x+202,y,tel_MOV)
    canvas.drawString(x+282,y,dir_SEC)
    canvas.drawString(x+382,y,con_COM)
    lpp=lpp+1

    if lpp>65:
        canvas.showPage()
        lpp=0
        x=0
        y=705
        pag=pag+1
        encabezado(pag)

canvas.drawString(x,30,str(y))
canvas.save()
```

Comment: Tienes mucho espacion para explicar cual es tu problema, lee [ask]

Comment: El programa se ejecuta en la consola y el IDLE, pero no con pythonw.exe.

Comment: El programa se ejecuta en la consola y en el IDLE, pero no con pythonw.exe.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añadelo alli, ¿has leido el enlace que te mostre?

Comment: La situacion es, el programa imprime un reporte simple en reportlab, lo ejecuta perfectamente en el IDLE y en la consola, pero utilizando pythonw, desde un icono no...

Comment: Roberto lee el enlace que @eyllanesc te mostró y agrega la información a la pregunta, no a los comentarios. Cuando alguien que pueda que sepa la respuesta vea, no se va a animar a responder por falta de información.

Comment: @NeryOrtez yo no soy él que creo el post.

Comment: Cierto... Mezclé nombres. Mis disculpas. Que vergüenza xD

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente entramos al buscador "Buscar Sistema Windows (C):" Parte derecha y registramos pythonw.
Aparecieron varios (pythonw.exe), en varias direcciones, en nuestro caso dejamos unicamente el que estaba en el direcctorio de python con el que estamos trabajando. "pyton3.5.4", los demas los eliminamos y listo.
Al menos se ejecuto el debbuguer. pdb python.